# A Jet of Steam passed into a Block of Ice

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation

> A jet of steam at 100 degrees Centigrade is passed through an orifice drilled in a 2 kilogram cubic block of ice at 0 degrees Centigrade. After some time, the ice fully melts. Calculate the mass of the steam used.

My professor gave us a test this morning, and this question has been at the back of my head ever since. My question is, how would one go about solving this problem?

My initial approach was as follows:
$$(mc\Delta{T}+mL)_{ice}=(mc\Delta{T}+mL)_{steam}$$
$$(2000×4.2×(t-0))+(2000×336)=(x×4.2×(100-t))+(x×2268)$$
$$8400t+672000=420x-4.2xt+2268x$$
$$672000=2688x-4.2xt-8400t$$

And this is where I was stumped. Not knowing the final temperature of the mixture, I had no idea on how to proceed further. I changed my approach with the assumption that the steam is of just the right amount to bring the final temperature of the mixture to 100 degrees Centigrade. Therefore:

$$(mc\Delta{T}+mL)_{ice}=(mL)_{steam}$$
$$(2000×4.2×(100-0))+(2000×336)=(x×2268)$$
$$840000+672000=2268x$$
$$1512000=2268x$$
$$x≈666.67g≈0.67kg$$

Confident I got the right answer, I went to my professor once the examination was over and asked him whether this was the right answer to this problem. He replied the answer was approximately 0.26 kilograms.

We haven't received our papers back yet, and I'm sure my assumption was incorrect, but I have no idea of the correct mechanism for this process.
I would greatly appreciate any help anyone could provide.

Comment: I don't think the question is well defined.  You would have to make some assumptions about the heat transfer from the jet to the block, and that is impossible to do since no physical dimensions or flow rates are given. And, the dimensions of the orifice or duct would change as the ice melts.  It's a pretty interesting and complex problem, but underspecified.

Answer (score 0):

Just before all the ice had melted, the temperature of the mixture of water and ice was 0 C.  So, when the final bit of ice melts, the temperature will be 0 C.